# DST in Ruby not accurate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I am using Ruby on Rails to develop apps that include time zone conversion. One interesting thing found: Now is March.26 2013, and I set time zone to Athens and it seems to be already in DST (the Time.zone shows GMT +2 Athens, but the formatted time shows +0300). Then I changed to Cairo time, the formatted time goes back to +0200

However, according to http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2013.html, the DST change should happen on March.31. It should not be in DST yet.

Is it a bug in Ruby, or I made a mistake?

Edit:
I formatted a datetime from the database, which is April.1. So the program formatted that time and showing DST for "that" datetime, instead of showing it at current time.

My bad. Thank you all

Comment: Whats the code you are running?  What do you mean by changing the timezone.

Comment: It's really important that you show the code you're talking about, instead of asking us to imagine it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the UTC offest you are seeing is not what you might expect. If you are looking at the timezone, I believe the UTC offset does not change for DST, but if you deal with a specific time and ask for the UTC offset you will see what you expect.

```
> ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Athens'].now.utc_offset
=> 7200

> (ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Athens'].now+1.week).utc_offset
=> 10800
```

Comment: The takeway, I think, is to always deal with a specific time in a timezone, not with the timezone itself.

Comment: Thank you, this is the exact mistake I got into